# Scrolling stops when middle clicked element is removed from the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm waist deep in my own React virtualization implementation and one of the minor issues that has been annoying me is that if I middle click on an item in my list and start scrolling, once that element is removed from the DOM the scrolling halts. My first theory was that the element was gaining focus and that preventing that would solve the issue, but what I've tried hasn't been working and I'm not even sure that's the issue.

How can I prevent this from happening?

See this fiddle for a basic demonstration:

https://jsfiddle.net/v169xkym/2/

And the relevant bit of code that handles virtualization:

```
$('#container').scroll(function(e) {
  $('#container').children().each(function(i) {
     if ($('.item:eq(' + i + ')').length > 0) {
        if ($('.item:eq(' + i + ')').offset().top < 0) {
          $('.item:eq(' + i + ')').remove();
          $('#topPadding').height($('#topPadding').height() + 45);
        }
     }
  });
});
```

Basically, I'm using the standard method of removing the element and upping the padding. In my React implementation this is handled different but here you get a basic functional representation.

Comment: this is super vague, you've gotta share some code

Comment: That will be difficult as the code is proprietary and rather large. I can try to create a small proof of concept that demonstrates the issue at some point if I don't get any good leads from the answers / feedback here.

Comment: Create a minimal version that is representative of your issue and provide it.

Comment: i have the exact same problem with my own app, its not proprietary, so i will share some code

Comment: @gorhawk Wondering if you were able to figure this out or if you could share some code here? I haven't been able to get around to this as it's pretty low on my priority list at the moment.

Comment: it's my personal project, so it hasn't moved anywhere since :) :(
i'll try sharing code, but i had difficulties trying to produce a minimal example..

Comment: I have added a fiddle to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: everything works fine in chrome 66 though. I don't know what is going on..

Comment: @gorhawk Steps to reproduce are pretty simple. Middle click on the top item and then move the mouse down so it starts scrolling down. As soon as the top item is removed from the DOM scrolling will stop.

Answer (score 1):

you can get around this by not having the disappearing element register mouse events.

this can be done with CSS3 :

```
div.item {
    pointer-events : none;
}
```

(Not entirely sure why, but my guess is that once the element disappears, the origin of the event is missing, so browsers simply stop doing what they were doing.)

[Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4r38kx43/1/)

Comment: This ends up breaking interaction with nested form elements, which my use case requires. That said, this is a good enough improvement for me to move forward since I can just re enable on the form elements. Seems acceptable enough if this issue only occurs when you middle click on a form element. I'll accept this answer in a few days if someone doesn't come along with a better universal option. Thanks!

Comment: i'm not 100% sure why one would want to remove elements while scrolling. isn't simply hiding them a better idea?

Comment: "Windowing" allows you to drastically improve performance on large lists of items, think thousands of DOM heavy React elements. By only rendering what is visible in the window, the browser doesn't have to build all these extra items and React doesn't have to propagate prop changes, etc to them. I've found it basically eliminates that performance cost and lets you render ludicrously large and complex lists

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late to the party. A workaround I am using on a virtual scroller is to detect when there is a scroll event, and when there has been no new events for a time, I consider the scroll is complete.

```
let scrollTimer = null;
let isScrolling = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
  isScrolling = true;
  
  scrollTimer = setTimeout(()=>{
    isScrolling = false;
  },500);
}, false);
```

I then grab a reference to the element that is hovered at the time isScrolling becomes true (using mouseOver) and prevent this element being unloaded until isScrolling is false. It is a bit of a juggle, but works. I am hoping I can find something simpler as it only seems to be a Chrome problem.

Update: It seems to be a known bug, about to be fixed related to pointer-events: none on something that overlays a virtual scroller (reproduction by someone https://codepen.io/flachware/pen/WNMzKav). I have no idea why my work around above works, but nice to know it wont be needed come Chrome 103. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1330045&q=chrome%20scroll&can=2&sort=-opened